# Getting array_push result from function

Tags: php, laravel

in this below code i used `array_push` in the main function

```php
$postsList = [];
foreach ($categories->posts as $post) {
    array_push($postsList, $post);
}
```

and after this operation i used this code:

```php
$this->child($categories,$postsList);
```

`child` is a function which into that i used `$postsList` and my problem is i can't return latest value of that to main function

full code:

```php
public function index()
{
    ...
    $postsList = [];
    foreach ($categories->posts as $post) {
        array_push($postsList, $post);
    }


    array_push($postsList, $this->child($categories, $postsList));
    dd($postsList);
}

private function child($categories,$postsList)
{
    if ($categories->childrenCategories->first()) {
        foreach ($categories->childrenCategories as $childCategory) {
            foreach ($childCategory->categories as $category) {
                foreach ($category->posts as $post) {
                    array_push($postsList,$post);
                }
            }

            foreach ($childCategory->posts as $post) {
                array_push($postsList,$post);
            }
            $this->child($childCategory,$postsList);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand is that you are trying to pluck out the posts from categories nested under root categories.

Try the below

```php
//Eager load all relations on the Category records

$categories = Category::with(['posts', 'childrenCategories.posts', 'childrenCategories.categories.posts'])->get();

public function getPosts($categories)
{
      //Get all Posts from the root level categories
      $postList = collect($categories->pluck('posts')->all());

      $categories->each(function($category) use(&$postList){

        if ($category->childrenCategories->count()) {

            $category->childrenCategories->each(function ($childCategroy) use (&$postList){
                //Get all Posts from child categories of root level categories
                $postList->push($childCategroy->posts);

                //Get all Posts from the categories of child category
                $postList->push($childCategroy->categories->pluck('posts')->all());
            });
        }

      });

      return $postList->unique('id')->all();
}
```

Then in the main function you can just call `getPosts($categories)`

```php
public function main()
{
    $postList = $this->getPosts($categories);
}
```

Another way this could be accomplished it to make a query to get ids of all categories with nested categories. Then make a simple query to the posts table to get all posts where category_id is within the array.

Comment: `posts` and `categories` are `ManyToMany` and passed `categories` has `posts` in `relations` and `$categories->pluck('posts')` return `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'posts' in 'field list' (SQL: select `posts` from `categories` where `categories`.`deleted_at` is null)` error

Comment: If you have eager loaded posts on categories then pluck should work. $categories = Category::with('posts')->get() then $categories->pluck('posts') should not give any errors like column not found, because then we are using pluck on a collection of categories with posts reation

Comment: @Donkarnashmy Query is : `$categories = Category::with(['childrenCategories' => function ($query) {$query->with('posts');}, 'posts'])`

Comment: @DolDurma Have updated answer to show eager load all relations (sample code). Let me know if it works

Comment: i checked, this code which i used `$categories = Category::with(['posts', 'childrenCategories.posts', 'childrenCategories.categories.posts'])->get();` return 233 row  and when i try to dump it as `dd($categories->childrenCategories);` i get `Property [childrenCategories] does not exist on this collection instance.` error. in my model i have `childrenCategories` not `childCategories`

Comment: Oops.. sorry for that. You should use the relation names which you have defined on your model. Will update the answer

Comment: @DolDurma Does this work for you as intended?

Comment: Your latest updated code, it doesn't work and i get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225743/discussion-between-doldurma-and-donkarnash).

Answer (score 2):

You can manage them by sending the same copy of `postsList` using reference `&` like below in the function parameter.

```
private function child($categories,&$postsList)
{
    if ($categories->childrenCategories->first()) {
        foreach ($categories->childrenCategories as $childCategory) {
            foreach ($childCategory->categories as $category) {
                foreach ($category->posts as $post) {
                    array_push($postsList,$post);
                }
            }

            foreach ($childCategory->posts as $post) {
                array_push($postsList,$post);
            }
            $this->child($childCategory,$postsList);
        }
    }
}
```

In `index()` method, you don't need to `array_push()` again from the `child()` call, but rather just call the `child()` method.

```
public function index()
{
    ...
    $postsList = [];
    foreach ($categories->posts as $post) {
        array_push($postsList, $post);
    }


    $this->child($categories, $postsList);
    dd($postsList);
}
```